# Make elements in li align right properly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bunch of `<li>` and I want to align right all the buttons that I placed in it. Here is my attempt with Bootstrap 3.0.0:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <button type="button" class="close" style="float:right" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>   
        <a href="#" ng-click="clickItem(item)">{{item}}</a>             
    </li>
</ul>
```

I simply want to have all the x's align right, but it seems like based on the length of the `<a>` tag, the button is aligned to the right. I simply want, irrelevant of `<a>` tag length, to align the buttons properly. Here is an example of what's happening[image]

I just want it so that both x's align properly vertically and to the right. I tried adding `float:right` to the button, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: you need to have a costum width to be able to achieve that

Comment: Put a fixed width for list items.

Answer (score 0):

try `display: block` and `pull-right`:

```
 <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" style="display: block">
        <a href="#" ng-click="clickItem(item)">{{item}}</a>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT: wrap it with `div` and `display: block`
EDIT 2: make sure that `li` is **not** `inline`. Try the inspector

Comment: If i put the class="pull-right" in the a tag, then the a tag goes to the right which is not what I would want. I want it to stay on the left, but I want the  x to stay on the right.

Comment: make sure the your `li` is NOT `inline`

Answer (score 0):

What's happening when you use `float: right` is that the spacing on the element is overflowing the parent's causing the buttons to collide before they reach the end of the `li` element. Try adding `overflow: auto` or specify a height to the `li` element.

Answer (score 0):

Making your list items `display: block` might help the buttons float all the way to the right when adding `float:right`, assuming your layout allows that.

```css
.list-unstyled {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list-unstyled li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
  border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.list-unstyled li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.close {
  float: right;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    <a href="#">Fee</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    <a href="#">Fi</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    <a href="#">Foe</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    <a href="#">Fum</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The embedded styles here are just to make it obvious how the li renders when block.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it different way, I used `position` approach. At first try to use `CSS` selector instead inline style. See below:

```css
.style-selector {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 250px;
}
.style-selector > li {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 25px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.style-selector > li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.style-selector > li .close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -12px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<ul class="style-selector">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <a href="#" ng-click="clickItem(item)">{{item}}</a>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <a href="#" ng-click="clickItem(item)">{{item}}</a>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </li>
 </ul>
```